# After installing RDS on WinServer 2016 I still can only connect with two users?

Tags: active-directory, azure, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services, terminal

**What I'm trying to do:** I have a software that multiple users are supposed to use on one system. Because a standard installation of WinServer2016 can only hold a maximum of two users at once I googled and was told that a Terminal Server / RDS Server would remove this limitation so I tried that with the help of some tutorials.

All of this is happening in Azure.

**The problem:** I thought I had everything set up correctly but when I try to RDP into the machine with the third user it tells me that there's too many users and that I need to disconnect one of them to continue (as it would be if I had done nothing at all).

**What I did so far :**

- Installed a DC for my Terminal Server and let the Terminal Server join the Domain (set up the DC as DNS Server in the VNET, not in the TCP/IP Adapter settings)
- In Server Manager I started the Role and Features Menu, and chose install RDS, Quickstart, Session-Based, selected the Terminal Server
- Watched as it was installing, then had a disconnect, couldn't reconnect for a while, had to reset the connection configuration in azure and was able to reconnect.
- Upon login the installation window opened again and told me it was still doing something. After a few moments it completed with the statuss message "Successful".
- Installed the Licensing Server Role through the server manager, added my license through the server manager.
- opened gpedit.msc and made the following changes to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Session Host > Licensing :
  "Use the specified Remote Desktop license servers" > Enabled
  "Set the Remote Desktop licensing mode" > Enabled (per Device)
- Also in gpedit.msc, only in the directory Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections :
  Allow users to connect remotely by using RDS: Enabled
  Limit Number of connections: Enabled, Max Connections = 999999
  Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single RDS session = Disabled
  Allowed remote start of unlisted programs: Enabled

Still, not working. Maybe the settings reset has something to do with it? Or maybe I'm missing something obvious? Never used or set-up RDS before, except to RDP into my VMs on Azure...

Checked the RDS Events Log, found a few error messages:

> TB-TK-TERMINAL1   2056    Error   Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-SessionBroker    Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-SessionBroker/Operational    2/6/2018
>   10:53:33 AM
>
> The Remote Desktop Connection Broker server could not enumerate the targets for the provider named NULL from the database.
>
> Pooled virtual desktop collection name: NULL
>   Error: Logon to the database failed.

I googled this message, but only got responses saying that my Domain is old. I created this domain specifically on/for a WinServer2016 so I doubt that this is the case.

> TB-TK-TERMINAL1   1280    Warning Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-SessionBroker-Client Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-SessionBroker-Client/Operational 2/6/2018
>   10:55:01 AM
>
> Remote Desktop Services failed to join the Connection Broker on server
>   tb-tk-terminal1.domainname.local. Error: Current async message was
>   dropped by async dispatcher, because there is a new message which will
>   override the current one.

Comment: Did you create a session collection, etc?  Can you show a screenshot of server manager and the installed roles, etc?  In session-based setups, I have found that you have to publish at least one app for it all to work (even if you plan to just RDP to the server)

Answer (score 1):

For the basic setup under

- Remote Desktop Service

You will need to make-sure you have installed and configured

- RD Connection Broker
- RD Session Host
- RS Licensing

The error above looks as though the the database that the Connection Broker uses can't be accessed, by default it will use a windows internal database unless you have configured the server as High Availability using a shared databases.

If you run through the Remote Desktop Services Installer again to verify your installation.

It is not recommended to run Remote Desktop Services role and Active Directory Domain services on the same server, I am guessing your DC is separate but your are not clear in your in question. Personally I would never run it in Server 2012 Environment it was next to impossible and required an update.